# How to understand the following code, this serves as a pipe in an Angular project

Tags: angular, filter

**Background:**

I am building a SIM project with Angular 7. 
Using this following pipe to select the corresponding items inside an array(list[]), and display it to the UI. With the title(filterField) of each item and input string(keyword).

therefore I have the following code:

pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list:any[], filterField:string, keyword:string){
    if(!filterField || !keyword){return list;}else{
      return list.filter(item =>{
          let fieldValue = item[filterField];
          return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword)>=0;
        }  
      )
    }
  }
}
```

These are the list [] details:

```
 private products: Product[] = [
    new Product(1, '1st Product', 1.99, 3.5, 'This is the 1st product, which is used for display', ['Electronics', 'Hardware']),
    new Product(2, '2nd Product', 2.99, 2.5, 'This is the 2nd product, which is used for display', ['Books']),
    new Product(3, '3rd Product', 3.99, 4.5, 'This is the 3rd product, which is used for display', ['Hardware']),
    new Product(4, '4th Product', 4.99, 1.5, 'This is the 4th product, which is used for display', ['Electronics', 'Hardware']),
    new Product(5, '5th Product', 5.99, 3.5, 'This is the 5th product, which is used for display', ['Electronics']),
    new Product(6, '6th Product', 6.99, 2.5, 'This is the 6th product, which is used for display', ['Books'])
  ]


export class Product {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public price: number,
    public rating: number,
    public desc: string,
    public categories: Array<string>
  ) {
  }
}
```

product.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Please Input" [formControl]="titleFilter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div *ngFor="let product of products | filter:'title':keywordInput" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x150">
    <div class="caption">
      <h4 class="pull-right">{{product.price}} Euro</h4>
      <h4><a [routerLink]="['/product',product.id]">{{product.title}}</a></h4>
      <p>{{product.desc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <app-stars [rating]="product.rating"></app-stars>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

product.component.ts

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

products:Array<Product>;
keywordInput:string;
titleFilter:FormControl=new FormControl;

  constructor(private productService:ProductService) {
    this.titleFilter.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(
        value => this.keywordInput = value,
      );
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products=this.productService.getProducts();

  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. how to understand

```
itemTitle => {
          let fieldValue = itemTitle[filterField];
          return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0;
        }
```

I could not understand the itemTitle[filterField] part, I assume itemTitle is the title of each item, but how does the  [ ] works?

2. is .filter already deprecated in Angular 7? Is there an alternative for that?
3. for the following part

```
return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0;
```

could I use this for alternative?

```
if (fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
  return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword)
} else {return null;}
```

When I run it, it is not working,

thank you!

Comment: Please show a sample content of the `list`

Comment: Can you show the html code with sample values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to understand
>
> ```
> itemTitle => {
>       let fieldValue = itemTitle[filterField];
>       return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0;
> }
> ```

It is probably `item` not `itemTitle` in your code.
So `item` is each of the `Product` objects in the list.

`filterField` is the second argument to the pipe, which in your case is `title`.

`let fieldValue = itemTitle[filterField];` will fetch the `title` of the product object. Which can be "1st Product", "2nd Product", etc.

`fieldValue.indexOf(keyword)` will look for the presence of the `keyword` value(probably what you type in an input box) in the `fieldValue` string. If the `keyword` is present in the string, then it will return the starting index, if not it will return `-1`

`return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0;` will return `true` or `false` depending on whether the `keyword` string was present in the the title or not.

> is .filter already deprecated in Angular 7? Is there an alternative for that?

No, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method on JavaScript's Array prototype, it has nothing to do with angular here. And no, it is not deprecated.

> could I use this for alternative?
>
> ```
> if (fieldValue.indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
>   return fieldValue.indexOf(keyword)
> } else {return null;}
> ```

No, you can't use this to achieve what being achieved already.
You see, if you are using Array filter, if you want to remove an item from the Array, you return a falsy value, if you want to keep an element, you return a truthy value. In this code of yours, you are returning either the index of the found string or null. This will work in all the cases except when the found index will be `0`. If the keyword was found at the start itself then that product object will be removed from the list since you will be returning `0` (which is falsy).

Comment: @puddlejumper26 if it pleases, you can also accept the answer :P

Comment: yes, of course! Sorry I am new here, always forgot to accept!  :D

Comment: @puddlejumper26 yeah, no problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I assume itemTitle is the title of each item, but how does the [ ] works?

It's property accessor. It's not an Angular thing, it's a JS thing. Basically, `obj['foo']` is an equivalent of `obj.foo`, but with the `[]` notation the name of the property can be dynamic, it can be passed as an argument. Just like in your pipe.

Comment: thanks a lot!  it gives me some clues, I think I got it!